# Seagate expansion 1TB USB 3.0 on USB 2.0

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, power-supply, power, usb-storage

I'd like to buy [this drive](http://photos04.istore.pl/43103/photos/big/17126269.jpg) (Seagate 1TB Expansion USB 3.0), but I have USB 2.0 only. Do I need an external power supply? Will 500mA of USB 2.0 be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most 2.5" drives 500mA current of USB 2.0 is enough. Some old drives have another USB plug to get more current when needed but most of the time they run properly with only 1 jack plugged in